# SQL Server CURSOR not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Need a cursor to update a value from another stored procure and updates only selected values

I have the following:

```
DECLARE upd_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT * FROM Terr
WHERE Text = "RightT" ;

OPEN upd_cursor;

-- Perform the first fetch.
FETCH NEXT FROM upd_cursor;

-- Check @@FETCH_STATUS to see if there are any more rows to fetch.
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

 exec usp_Gent  @valback OUTPUT; 
 update Terr  
 set Text = @valback

FETCH NEXT FROM upd_cursor;
END

CLOSE upd_cursor;
DEALLOCATE upd_cursor;
GO
```

In my case, it updates all of the field in the table. What am I doing wrong

Comment: You are not using update syntax for cursors.  Your code will update all rows in the Terr table every time you loop.  That being said.  Agree with below.  No reason to use a cursor in this case.  Better off with an Upadate... where"

Comment: I don't know. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *really* wanted to do a row by row update you could use `CURRENT OF` syntax. This would be the case if your call to the stored procedure returned different results on each.

e.g.

```
     update Terr  
     set Text = @valback
     WHERE CURRENT OF upd_cursor
```

Comment: My goal is to iterate through record and I have a stored procedure that generates a value, assign that value during the update. Is there a better and more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: @NatePet Well you could write an SP that does a set based retrieval and update the table all in one go. Another option is to rewrite SP as a function and use CROSS APPLY (SQL 2005 and later). There are limitations however on what can be a function

Answer (score 3):

```
update Terr  
set Text = @valback
```

You aren't setting a `WHERE` condition in this statement.

Also, why are you using cursors?

Comment: +1 for right answer +1 for questioning use of cursor.  I can't +2 can I?

Answer (score 3):

You have no where clause on your `update` statement.

More generically, you should use a single `update` clause to do this rather than a cursor:

```
exec usp_Gent @valback OUTPUT;
update Terr set
    Text = @valback
where
    Text = 'RightT';
```

Unless you're `usp_Gent` is doing something that I'm missing.

The reason you want a single clause instead of doing one *for each row* is because SQL thinks better in sets. Each `update` you have has overhead--it opens up a transaction, records what it's doing, and then commits that transaction. This is remarkably slow if you have to do thousands of these. What you really want to do is just update thousands of row at once--this is what databases do with relational algebra, and they are really, really good at doing it. Think in sets, not in order.

Comment: Ditto.  Unless usp_Gent is supposed to return unique values each time for each row being updated, this is the most elegant and performant solution.